# How to read octet-stream response

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, linkedin-api

I'm trying to post video to LinkedIn using Python.

I was able to post video using curl commands.

In step 2 curl command:

```bash
curl -v \
 -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" \
 --upload-file ~/Downloads/sample.mp4 \
"https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C5505AQH-oV1qvnFtKA/uploadedVideo?sau=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGlua2VkaW4tZWkuY29tL2FtYnJ5L2FtYnJ5LXZpZGVvZWkvP3gtbGktYW1icnktZXA9QVFHVkdRS0FtS05oM2dBQUFYd19ObG1uZzVYcllXajEzZjIybXh4LW55SGVBclVKcE8y"
```

and we get a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
etag: /ambry-videoei/signedId/AQHX97-zKFZrewAAAXx7Kf1h4pHEr_EVJ2_BGyigpJdmMfO9DreqqynKhTXcMMtKmFtM_JL07JFHXfzHoegWPUsBw9ofV7Z3KWfKRvB41FtIXq9pmvQtkDNrw_nPX4QjsDktxxzFq2gMlC9e3H4x8U_y0QQFQO0pMvtdwaBoFZ_eq_hGZRQCG-zTcYD0J_Nqsf1bApcZ_KGM3Zdc62eATjUTAV7zH4f--18-PLbhQMkKl4g9tjzgRVVv3jp3EPwRidBb7bk0RSI.bin
```

When converted to Python, it is:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
}

params = {
    'sau': 'aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGlua2VkaW4tZWkuY29tL2FtYnJ5L2FtYnJ5LXZpZGVvZWkvP3gtbGktYW1icnktZXA9QVFHVkdRS0FtS05oM2dBQUFYd19ObG1uZzVYcllXajEzZjIybXh4LW55SGVBclVKcE8y',
}

with open('~/Downloads/sample.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

response = requests.put(
    'https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C5505AQH-oV1qvnFtKA/uploadedVideo',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
    data=data
)

response 

<Response [200]>
```

I want `etag` from `response` to proceed to further steps. So I tried:

```py
data = json.loads(response.content)
```

When I `print(response.content)`, I get:

```py
b ' '
```

I also tried

```
print(response.json())
```

And I got this error:

```py
File "xxxxx/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 917, in json raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos) requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] : 0
```

Can anyone help me in getting response from in particular etag from this code.

Comment: Did you try something like `etag = data['etag']`?

Comment: Yes, I tried this however got this response

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

when I'm trying to print the response I'm getting only this much
<Response [200]>

Unlike the curl response which has all the details.

Comment: What is the output of `print(response.json())`?

Comment: I got this response for response.json()

File "xxxxx/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 917, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] : 0

Comment: OK. Now what is the output of `print(response.content)`? Update the question with those two results, please. That will help others to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some deep dive was able to find answer to my question. I checked more on what is ETag and what is it's use, found out that it is a part of headers section so just tried

`response.headers`

and was able to get ETag

And to extract ETag I tried

```
    etag = respHeaders['ETag']
```

Now I'm able to successfully upload video to LinkedIn.